# Get User Input from HTML in TypeScript WITHOUT using React or Angular

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

The goal of my current code is to take in the user's input for "se" and "sp" in the .html code and if the input is "billy" and "bronco" respectively it should give the alert("success")

I am very new to TypeScript, but my .ts is transpiled to .js.
Currently only the alert("wrong username or password") runs, no matter what the input is.
**the code does not use the alert("success") even if the input is correct**
I was wondering what I am doing wrong, because, for this project, **I don't want to use React or Angular**. Is it possible to do accomplish what I want without using those?

> this is my .ts code:

```
interface LoginInfo{
    username: string;
    password: string;
}
class LoginTs{
    username: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(username: string, password: string ) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;


        let submitBtn = document.getElementById("enter")
        submitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e: Event) => {


            return loginTs.validateInput(iUser, iPass)
        });


        let forgotBtn= document.getElementById("forgotPass")
        forgotBtn.addEventListener("click",(e:Event) =>loginTs.forgotPassword());
    }

    forgotPassword(){
        return alert("tough luck lmao")
    }

    validateInput(user:any, pass:any){
         if(user =="billy" && pass =="bronco1"){
             alert("success")
         }
         else{
             alert("wrong username or password")
         }
    }
}

let iUser =(document.getElementById("se") as HTMLInputElement).value;
let iPass =(document.getElementById("sp") as HTMLInputElement).value;
let loginTs = new LoginTs(iUser,iPass);
```

> this is my .html code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Capstone Typescript Login</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<header>
    <h2>Billy Bronco's Grading Calculator</h2>
</header>

<div id="container">

    <div id="tabs">

        <p id="lt" class="tabs" onclick="loginTabFun()">Log in</p>
        <p id="rt" class="tabs" onclick="regTabFun()">Register</p>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Login.css">

        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="cont">

        <div id="login" class="comm">
            <h3>Sign in</h3>

            <input id="se" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
            <input id="sp" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>

            <input type="button" class="button" id="enter" value="Login">
            <input type="button" class="button" id="forgotPass" value="Forgot Password?">

        </div>



    </div>

</div>
<script src="LoginTs.js"></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

> and this is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "files" : ["../typings/tsd.d.ts", "LoginTs.ts"]
}
```

> Thank You!

**FIXED CODE**

> .ts

```
interface LoginInfo{
    username: string;
    password: string;
}
class LoginTs{
    username: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(username: string, password: string ) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;


        let submitBtn = document.getElementById("enter")
        submitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e: Event) => {
            //let iUser =(document.getElementById("se") as HTMLInputElement).value;
           // let iPass =(document.getElementById("sp") as HTMLInputElement).value;

            return LoginTs.validateInput(this.username,this.password)
        });


        let forgotBtn= document.getElementById("forgotPass")
        forgotBtn.addEventListener("click",(e:Event) =>LoginTs.forgotPassword());
    }
    private static validateInput(username: string, password: string) {
        if(username =="billy" && password =="bronco1"){
            alert("success")
        }
        else{
            alert("wrong username or password")
        }
    }

    private static forgotPassword() {
        return alert("tough luck lmao")
    }
}
document.getElementById("enter").addEventListener("click", function() {
    let iUser =(document.getElementById("se") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let iPass =(document.getElementById("sp") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let loginTs = new LoginTs(iUser,iPass);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the value of the inputs when the page loads, and the input boxes have a default value of `''` (an empty string). Get the value of the input boxes when you click the Login button.

```
interface LoginInfo{
    username: string;
    password: string;
}
class LoginTs{
    username: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(username: string, password: string ) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;


        let submitBtn = document.getElementById("enter")
        submitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e: Event) => {


            return loginTs.validateInput(iUser, iPass)
        });


        let forgotBtn= document.getElementById("forgotPass")
        forgotBtn.addEventListener("click",(e:Event) =>loginTs.forgotPassword());
    }

    forgotPassword(){
        return alert("tough luck lmao")
    }

    validateInput(user:any, pass:any){
         if(user =="billy" && pass =="bronco1"){
             alert("success")
         }
         else{
             alert("wrong username or password")
         }
    }
}

document.getElementById("enter").addEventListener("click", function() {
    let iUser =(document.getElementById("se") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let iPass =(document.getElementById("sp") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let loginTs = new LoginTs(iUser,iPass);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! This worked! I just had to fix up a bit of my functions, and the fixed code will be updated in my question!

Answer (score 1):

You're grabbing the login and password values out of the elements when the page is first loaded, rather than doing it at the time when the user tries to submit. Move that logic into the submit event listener:

```
    submitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e: Event) => {

        let iUser =(document.getElementById("se") as HTMLInputElement).value;
        let iPass =(document.getElementById("sp") as HTMLInputElement).value;

        return loginTs.validateInput(iUser, iPass)
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I did this when I started, but it causes problems when I call LoginTs, because there's no parameters to take when I call it?

Comment: @ErinB: Redesign your LoginTs class. There's no reason to take username and password as constructor arguments.